# Django -Detailview object not found returning ascii error

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, detailview

I have a problem so the problem is I have a DetailView. When the object is not found, I get:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: ��quip

Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get
  110.         self.object = self.get_object()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_object
  55.                           {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /teams/arsenal-3-66/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It does this instead of returning a 404....

I don't know what to do.

The detail view is simple:

```
class TeamDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Team
    template_name = 'teams/team.html'
```

And the model is simple also:

```
class Team(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name=_("name"))
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True,populate_from='name')

    class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Équipe'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Équipes'

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 2.7: def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: You haven't shown any details of what is generating that error. What does the DetailView look like? What does the model look like, especially the `__unicode__` method? Why do you think the object is not found?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited the original post

Answer (score 1):

Well it was a dumb error.

All I had to do was:

```
class Meta:
   verbose_name = u'Équipe'
   verbose_name_plural = u'Équipes'
```